# Query to find entries and transpose

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've got a machine log available in an SQL table. I can do a bit in SQL, but I'm not good enough to process the following:

In the data column there are entries containing "RUNPGM: Recipe name" and "RUNBRKPGM: Recipe name"
What I want is a view containing 4 columns:

- TimeStamp RUNPGM
- TimeStamp RUNBRKPGM
- Recipe Name
- Time Difference in seconds

There is a bit of a catch:

- Sometimes the machine logs an empty RUNBRKPGM that should be ignored
- The RUNBRKPGM is sometimes logged with an error message. This entry should also be ignored.
  It's always the RUNBRKPGM entry with just the recipe name that's the actual end of the recipe.

[image: Screenshot table]

Comment: Sorry I forgot 1 thing: the table in the screenshot is already filtered on the desired entries. There are a lot of other entries in between them. None of them contain the RUNPGM or RUNBRKPGM String

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Some hints to get you started you can use CASE statement and substring functionality.  Or write your own Split string functionality (newer versions of SQL have that built in)

Comment: Hi Brad, I did try a few things with the CASE statement. But how will I be sure that I have the timestamps with the corresponding recipe names?

Answer (score 0):

NOTE:  I understand this is not a full/complete answer, but with info available in question as of now, I believe it at least helps give a starting point since this is too complicated (and formatted) to put in the comments:

If Recipe is everything in the DATA field except the 'RUNPGM = ' part you can do somethign similar to this:

```
SELECT 
-- will give you a col for TimeStamp for records with RUNPGM
CASE WHEN DATA LIKE 'RUNPGM%' THEN TS ELSE '' END AS RUNPGM_TimeStamp,
-- will give you a col for TimeStamp for records with RUNBRKPGM
CASE WHEN DATA LIKE 'RUNBRKPGM%' THEN TS ELSE '' END AS RUNBRKPGM_TimeStamp,
-- will give you everything after the RUNPGM = (which I think is the recipe you are referring to)
CASE WHEN DATA LIKE 'RUNPGM%' THEN REPLACE(DATA, 'RUNPGM = ', '' AS RUNPGM_Recipe,
-- will give you everything after the RUNBRKPGM = (which I think is the recipe you are referring to)
CASE WHEN DATA LIKE 'RUNBRKPGM:%' THEN REPLACE(DATA, 'RUNBRKPGM = ', '' AS RUNPGM_Recipe
FROM TableName
```

Im not sure what columns you want to get the Time Difference on though so I dont have that column in here.

Then if you need to do additional logic/formatting on the columns once they are separated you can put the above in a sub select.

Answer (score 0):

As a first swing, I'd try the following:

1. Create a view that uses string splitting to break the DATA column into a its parts (e.g. RunType and RecipeName)
2. Create a simple select that outputs the recipe name and tstamp where the runtype is RUNPGM.
3. Then add an OUTER APPLY:

Essentially, joining onto itself.

```
  SELECT
                t1.RecipeName,
                t1.TimeStamp AS Start,
                t2.TimeStamp AS Stop
                --date func to get run time, pseudo DATEDIFF(xx,t1.TimeStamp, t2.TimeStamp) as RunTime
FROM            newView               t1
    OUTER APPLY ( SELECT    TOP ( 1 )  *
                  FROM      newView x
                  WHERE     x.RecipeName = t1.RecipeName
                            AND RunType = 'RUNBRKPGM'
                  ORDER BY  ID DESC ) t2
WHERE           t1.RunType = 'RUNPGM';
```